# сборщик мусора. DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, сборщик-мусора

У меня есть функция, которая генерирует уведомления при помощи создания DOM элементов:

```js
function createNotification(content) {
  let notificationNode = document.createElement("div");
  let notificationDescrNode = document.createElement("p");
  let notificationButtonNode = document.createElement("span");
  notificationNode.classList.add("notification");
  notificationDescrNode.classList.add("notification__descr");
  notificationButtonNode.classList.add("notification__button");
  notificationDescrNode.innerHTML = content;
  notificationButtonNode.innerHTML = "ok";
  document.body.appendChild(notificationNode);
  notificationNode.appendChild(notificationDescrNode);
  notificationNode.appendChild(notificationButtonNode);
  document.body.classList.add("page_overflow_hidden");

  notificationButtonNode.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    document.body.classList.remove("page_overflow_hidden");
    document.body.removeChild(notificationNode);
    notificationNode = null;
    notificationDescrNode = null;
    notificationButtonNode = null;
  });
}

createNotification("Попробуйте через несколько секунд!");
```

```css
.notification {
  min-width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 100;
  background: #000;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.notification__descr {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.notification__button {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #000;
}
```

Подскажите, как правильно писать код, что бы не забивать память. В примере я удалю DOM узел, но так как он был создан при помощи метода `document.createElement` и храниться в переменной, то несмотря на то, что я удалю элемент, у обработчика событий все равно остается ссылка.

В связи с этим, я всем переменным присвоил значение `null`, но по идеи необходимо присвоить только для `notificationButtonNode`, так как остальные переменные очищаюсь, ибо нет на них ссылок.

Comment: Внутри обработчика удаляйте это событие.

Comment: Почему Вы считаете, что здесь нужны какие-то дополнительные действия (обнуление переменных) для сборки мусора?

Comment: @Igor, потому что удалив элемент со страницы, в переменной остается ссылка, на основе которой элемент создавался, а обработчик события привязан к этой переменной. Если бы я до конца понимал механизм, но не задавал бы вопрос)

Comment: Может подойдёт решение по типу того, что делают в react. При создании каждого уведомления вы создание новую функцию для кнопки. Но если вынести эту функцию за пределы функции создания уведомления и потом ссылаться на нее при навешиванием обработчика, то новая функция создаваться не будет.

Comment: @MishaSaidov, буду благодарен, если перефразируете ваш комментарий. Несколько раз перечитал, и не особо уловил идею.

Comment: Отвечал с телефона, не заметил грамматические ошибки. В общем, перечитал ваш вопрос. Я видимо не так вас понял, но вот тут вроде [подробно объяснили](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847220/javascript-document-createelement-delete-domelement)

Comment: @MishaSaidov, я постараюсь перевести и уловить суть, но меня еще заинтересовало ваше предложение, по поводу функции. я бы его хотел понять более развернуто.

Comment: Смотри: если ты знаком с реактом, в нем компоненты постоянно пересоздаются и, если на каком-то компоненте висит обработчик события, то при неправильном его навешивании, при каждом создании этого элемента эта функция будет создаваться снова и снова, а предыдущая останется в памяти. ([документация](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)). У вас немного другая проблема, но и в вашем случае ф-я внутри `notificationButtonNode.addEventListener` будет создаваться снова и снова, поэтому я хотел предложить вам вынести ее в отдельную переменную и обращаться потом к ней

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87652/discussion-between---and-misha-saidov).

Answer (score 0):

После удаления элемента `notificationNode` из дерева страницы образуется замкнутая гроздь объектов - элементы, обработчик, замыкание - ни с чем больше не связанная и подлежащая удалению. Современные браузеры в состоянии распознавать такие изолированные грозди объектов и удалять их.

Comment: почему тогда обработчик продолжает работать?
https://jsfiddle.net/Devinora/p6rza139/

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный Потому что в фидле есть еще один обработчик - `add.click`, который Вы не включили в вопрос и который хранит ссылку на `notificationButtonNode`.

Comment: я просто создал html файл и запустил его в браузере, и это так же работает. и я буду благодарен за ответ не по теме: почему нельзя добавить несколько одинаковых элементов? при повторной попытке, он просто не добавляется. можно использовать метод cloneNode, но это уже другая история.

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный Вы хотите, чтобы я объяснил код, которого не вижу?

Comment: По поводу первого вопроса, я продемонстрировал на jsfiddle, и так же его проверил создав html файл и поведение не поменялось. Вот код по поводу второго вопроса: https://jsfiddle.net/Devinora/4b5rfynd/

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный Вы понимаете, что код в вопросе и фидле - разный?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87647/discussion-between---and-igor).